# Counting sublists of a list in C#

Tags: c#, list

I have a List of Lists, call it listholder. I want to count how many lists listholder contains. listholder.count() does not seem to work (no definition).

I declared it this way:

```
List<List<T>> listholder = new List<List<T>>();
```

and tried

```
listholder.count()
```

Comment: Might want to add some code

Comment: He stated listholder.count isn't working.

Comment: Count() not count() - C# is case-sensitive

Comment: @davenewza That's what it was! Thanks. Didn't realize that.

Comment: For the record, I think it is completely silly that this question was closed.

Comment: Not sure why this was closed either...

Comment: Same.  The question seems reasonable.

Comment: please paste your code. Am sure list.count's record is clean. We cant find it guilty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`listholder.Count()` will return the number of elements in that list, i.e. the number of lists it contains.

Comment: Yes, this is what I am after.